# How to find out which 3rd party libraries actually accessing permission-protected data on Android?

Tags: android

There was a new feature in android ecosystem roughly in 2020 that allowing to track when permission protected data (like location) is accessed by 3rd party library of your app, but I cannot find which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

It was [data access audiitng](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/audit-access) I was searching for.